# Google Workspace API - How to GET Devices (Computers NOT Mobile Devices)

Tags: google-api, google-workspace

I'm looking to perform a GET to retrieve details of a users devices (computers) to perform actions in a similar way that I can for mobile devices.

Please advise if this is possible.

Cannot find API to get users devices that aren't mobile devices

Comment: Which one are you using for mobile devices

Comment: This gets me all Mobile Devices with a given email address

https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/devices/mobile?query=email:test@test.com

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for that call

Comment: This is for mobile - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/mobiledevices/list

There is no API that I can find for endpoints IE Computers.